# Why can nested child classes access private members of their parent class, but grandchildren cannot?

Tags: java, visibility, inner-classes

Probably similar to the question, [Why can outer Java classes access inner class private members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801718/why-can-outer-java-classes-access-inner-class-private-members) or [Access to superclass private fields using the super keyword in a subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478718/access-to-superclass-private-fields-using-the-super-keyword-in-a-subclass) .

But there are some differences: the children class can access the private members of their parent (and **only the nearest parent**) class.

Given the sample code below:

```
public class T {

    private int t;

    class T1 {
        private int t1;

        public void test() {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    class T2 extends T1 {

        private int t2;

        public void test() {
            System.out.println(t);
            System.out.println(super.t1);
            System.out.println(this.t2);
        }
    }

    class T3 extends T2 {

        public void test() {
            System.out.println(t);
            System.out.println(super.t1); // NG: t1 Compile error! Why?
            System.out.println(super.t2); // OK: t2 OK
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing two different things there: Class *nesting* (inner classes), and *subclassing*. But it's quite an interesting question. `T3` not being able to access `super.t1` makes sense; `T3`'s `super` doesn't have a `t1`. I have to admit not understanding why `T3` can access `t2` though. Inner classes are weird. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, but why `T2` can access `t1`... and only `T3` can NOT access `t1` ?

Comment: The simple answer is that `private` takes effect outside the outer class.

Comment: To add to that in most countries children accessing parent's privates is illegal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to superclass private fields using the super keyword in a subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478718/access-to-superclass-private-fields-using-the-super-keyword-in-a-subclass)

Comment: @DevNewb that was unnecessary...

Comment: ...But still funny.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Clever example! But it's actually a somewhat boring explanation - there's no visibility problem, you simply have no way of referring to `t1` directly from `T3` because [`super.super` isn't allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586363/113632).

`T2` can't access its own `t1` field directly since it's private (and child classes don't inherit their parent's private fields), but `super` is effectively an instance of `T1` and since it's in the same class `T2` can refer to the private fields of `super`. There's just no mechanism for `T3` to address the private fields of its grandparent class `T1` directly.

Both of these compile just fine inside `T3`, which demonstrates that a `T3` can access its grandparent's `private` fields:

```
System.out.println(((T1)this).t1);
System.out.println(new T1().t1);
```

Conversely this doesn't compile in either `T2` or `T3`:

```
System.out.println(t1);
```

If `super.super` were allowed you'd be able to do this from `T3`:

```
System.out.println(super.super.t1);
```

---

> if I'd define 3 classes, `A`, `B`, `C`, `A` having a protected field `t1` and `B` would inherit from `A` and `C` from `B`, `C` could refer to `A`s `t1` by invoking `super.t1` because it´s visible here. logically shouldn't the same apply to inner classes inheritance even if the field are private, because these private members should be visible due to being in the same class?

(I'm going to stick with OP's `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` class names for simplicity)

If `t1` were `protected` there'd be no problem - `T3` could refer to the `t1` field directly just like any subclass. The issue arises with `private` because a class has no *awareness* of its parent classes' `private` fields, and therefore can't reference them directly, even though in practice they are visible. That's why you have to use `super.t1` from `T2`, in order to even refer to the field in question.

Even though as far as a `T3` is concerned it has no `t1` field it has access into `T1`s `private` fields by being in the same outer class. Since that's the case all you need to do is cast `this` to a `T1` and you have a way to refer to the private field. The `super.t1` call in `T2` is (in essence) casting `this` into a `T1` letting us refer to its fields.

Comment: So `T3` can access `t2` because `T3` is part of `T`, and `T2` is part of `T`?

Comment: All of these classes have access to each others `private` fields, since they're all in the same outer-class.

Comment: @dimo414 But for normal inheritance i could refer to `t1` at each point of the inheritance by invoking `super.t1`. Why does it act different here?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal inheritance"? If these were all in separate files you wouldn't be able to address the parent classes private fields even via `super`.

Comment: @dimo414 if i´d define 3 classes, `A`, `B`, `C`, `A` having a `protected` field `t1` and `B` wouldinherit from `A` and `C` from `B`, `C` could refer to `A`´s `t1` by invoking `super.t1` because it´s visible here. logically Shouldn´t the same apply to inner classes inheritance even if the field are private, because these private members should be visible due to beeing in the same class? Or do i have a logical fault here?

Comment: @KevinEsche The difference is: Members declared as `protected` are _inherited_, whereas members declared as `private` are not. That means a field `protected int t1` is also a member of `B` (or `T2` as in the example), thus the access with `super.t2` in `C` (or `T3`) is allowed.

Comment: @KevinEsche updated my answer with your question; let me know if that still doesn't help.

Answer (score 15):

### Sythetic Accessor Methods

Technically, on the *JVM* level, you can **NOT** access any `private` members of another class — neither those of an enclosing class (`T.t`), nor those of a parent class (`T2.t2`). In your code it **just looks like** you can, because the compiler generates [**`synthetic`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.8) accessor methods for you in the accessed classes. The same happens when in the `T3` class you fix the invalid reference <s>`super.t1`</s> using the correct form `((T1) this).t1`.

With the help of such a compiler generated **`synthetic`** accessor method, you can in general access **any** `private` member of **any** class nested in the outer (top level) `T` class, e.g. from `T1` you can use `new T2().t2`. Note that this applies to `private static` members too.

The **`synthetic`** attribute was introduced in *JDK* release 1.1 to support nested classes, a new language feature in java at that time. Since then the *JLS* explicitly allows mutual access to all members within a top level class, including `private` ones.

But for backwards compatibility, the compiler unwraps nested classes (e.g. to `T$T1`, `T$T2`, `T$T3`) and translates `private` member **accesses** to **calls** to generated **`synthetic`** accessor methods (these methods thus need to have the *package private*, i.e. *default*, visibility):

```
class T {
    private int t;

    T() { // generated
        super(); // new Object()
    }

    static synthetic int access$t(T t) { // generated
        return t.t;
    }
}

class T$T1 {
    private int t1;

    final synthetic T t; // generated

    T$T1(T t) { // generated
        this.t = t;
        super(); // new Object()
    }

    static synthetic int access$t1(T$T1 t$t1) { // generated
            return t$t1.t1;
    }
}

class T$T2 extends T$T1 {
    private int t2;

    {
        System.out.println(T.access$t((T) this.t)); // t
        System.out.println(T$T1.access$t1((T$T1) this)); // super.t1
        System.out.println(this.t2);
    }

    final synthetic T t; // generated

    T$T2(T t) { // generated
        this.t = t;
        super(this.t); // new T1(t)
    }

    static synthetic int access$t2(T$T2 t$t2) { // generated
        return t$t2.t2;
    }
}

class T$T3 extends T$T2 {
    {
        System.out.println(T.access$t((T) this.t)); // t
        System.out.println(T$T1.access$t1((T$T1) this)); // ((T1) this).t1
        System.out.println(T$T2.access$t2((T$T2) this)); // super.t2 
    }

    final synthetic T t; // generated

    T$T3(T t) { // generated
        this.t = t;
        super(this.t); // new T2(t)
    }
}
```

N.B.: You're not allowed to refer to **`synthetic`** members directly, so in the source code you can't use e.g. `int i = T.access$t(new T());` yourself.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know any about `synthetic` until your answer.

Comment: @andyf: Check the update, I fixed the reference to the enclosing class `T`, which is propagated in another way -- through generated constructors and a synthetic member field. Note also, that the generated result varies between different compilers (openjdk, oracle, ibm, ...) -- they use different chaining patterns.

Comment: Synthetic methods are an implementation detail of the compiler, not part of the language spec. They're necessary because nested classes (and the unusual visibility privileges they have) weren't introduced until Java 1.2 and needed to work with prior bytecode. The synthetic `access$t1()` method makes `t1` accessible to both `T2` and `T3` since it's package-private. If the compiler wanted to it could add calls to `access$t1()` in `T3`.

Comment: @dimo414: But then it should be a part of JVM spec, shouldn't it? And **all** compilers need to work it around somehow (e.g. like above). Also, I don't get your last sentence, since there **is** a call to `T1.access$t1` in `T3` (eclipse compiler), no chaining.

Comment: The JVM spec and the language spec are different, and the latter isn't concerned with `synthetic` methods (though it might mention them in passing). They're an implementation detail to workaround a change in the language. My point in my last sentence was that there's nothing forbidding/preventing `T3` from calling `access$t1()` (if the compiler inserts it) according to the language spec. Put another way `T3` is permitted to access `t1` fields by the language, therefore the compiler is allowed to add calls to `access$t1()` inside `T3`.

Comment: My point is that the existence of `synthetic` methods doesn't explain OPs issue.

Comment: @dimo414: Yes, it doesn't, but your answer already did. Mine was complementary.

Comment: @dimo414 Your post really answers the question. But I'm really glad for the link to visible compiler internals, because "synthetic" is visible via Reflection.

Answer (score 7):

Very good finding! I think, we all had assumed that your code example should compile.

Unfortunately, it is not the case ... and the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) gives us an answer in [§15.11.2. "Accessing Superclass Members using super"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2) (emphasis mine):

> Suppose that a field access expression super.f appears within class C, and the **immediate** superclass of C is class S. If f in S is accessible from class C (§6.6), then super.f is treated as if it had been the expression this.f in the body of class S. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Accessibility is given because all fields are in the same enclosing class. They can be private but are still accessible.

The problem is that in `T2` (the *immediate* superclass of `T3`) the treatment of `super.t1` as `this.t1` is illegal - there is no field `t1` in `T2`. Hence the compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it explained how `super` works. But i accept another answer because the code `System.out.println(((T1)this).t1);` much easy to understand.